# Transferring Data From Iphone to Computer

Tags: ios, iphone, transfer

Is there any possible way to transfer data from an Iphone to the computer when the Iphone is tethered and an application is open.  Basically, the Iphone needs to be able to effect files on the computer.

Comment: Your question isn't that clear.  Are you wondering how to have an iPhone application communicate with a desktop client?  How to use the application to write to the desktop's file system?  How to control the desktop via an iPhone client?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there're two options for you:

1. **iTunes File Sharing** - This allows the user to browse the "Documents" directory of your application in iTunes. Your application will be in the background during this time. (the Sync screen takes priority) This however only works for changing files on the iOS device. You'll find a tutorial for that [here](http://maniacdev.com/2010/09/tutorial-enable-file-sharing-with-itunes-within-your-iphone-and-ipad-apps/).
2. **Wireless Transfer** - You could create a HTTP Server and allow the user to change files via their web browser or client application. This way, your app would not be in the background and you could technically monitor any changes you like. You can easily implement this for Mac OS X or iOS. For a tutorial for that, see [here](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/07/simple-extensible-http-server-in-cocoa.html).